# Realtime, SCHED_FIFO, CPU_SET()

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling, real-time

I'm trying to assign two real time processes to two cpus(one each). I'm using SCHED_FIFO scheduling policy.
I'm doing the following things:

- adding "quiet splash isolcpus = 6,7" at GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub to isolate cpus. I rebooted the system and it seems to work except a few kernel threads running on 6 and 7 cpus(I did that using top command).
- Then this:

  retval = sched_getattr(0, &attr, sizeof(struct sched_attr), 0);

  ```
  if(retval < 0){perror("Error in get attr:");return0;}
  ```

  attr.sched_policy = SCHED_FIFO;

  attr.sched_priority = 1;

  retval = sched_setattr(0,&attr,0);

  if(retval<0)
     {
       perror("Error setting sched params: ");
       return 0;
     }

  ```
  CPU_ZERO(&set);

  CPU_SET(7,&set);

  retval = sched_setaffinity(0,sizeof(cpu_set_t),&set);
      if(retval<0){perror("Affinity Error ");return 0;}
  ```

  I intend to run this process on cpu7. But I'm not able to do so. Why is it failing? Can you suggest other ways if it does not work this way?

Edit: I have not created any extra cpusets. There is only one cpuset directory in /sys/fs/cgroup

Answer (score 0):

Try to figure out, which error is returned. See

```
man 2 sched_setaffinity
```

Aside from that, you (the binary) need the capability "CAP_SYS_NICE" to change the affinity. So you must

- run the program as root, or
- set this capability on the binary (note:
  does not work on NFS mounted filesystems)

Setting the needed capabilty on the binary is done with

```
sudo setcap CAP_SYS_NICE+e <file>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I've tried both the options you've mentioned. But no luck. The code is compiling without errors. On the other hand, I've written a program without any SCHED_FIFO/SCHED_DEADLINE and used CPU_SET and sched_setaffinity(). It was working.

Comment: FYI, I use sockets and shared memory. Is that the reason why sched_setaffinity()  not working?

Comment: In the command "sudo setcap CAP_SYS_NICE+e <file>" , I think by file you meant the name of the executable.

Comment: Yes, the executable. 
Try to manually set the affinity on the running process from the commandline:

    $ > taskset -p <pid> # get
    $ > taskset -pc 4 <pid> # set to cpu 4

Comment: Does it work when run as root?

Comment: Nope. It did not work when I'm in root mode. I've created a sample application with SCHED_FIFO and set the cpu using CPU_SET and sched_setaffinity(). It was working! I've executed my sample application as root. Only then it worked. Otherwise it was throwing error at sched_setaffinity().